# How to Make atoi huge-numbers proof?

Tags: c, casting, atoi, long-long

hello I'm trying to recreate atoi in with some other added conditions, mainly computing how many signs and returning the number positive if number of minus even , otherwise negative, the script works fine. the problem it should be created with int type and it will be tested with some really big numbers, such as `19999999999` , I tried to cast it's return value but stupidly forget it will return always it's type.  any idea ? thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>

int ft_checksign(char *str)
{
    int i;
    int sign;

    sign = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (*(str + i))
    {
        if (*(str + i) == '-')
            sign += 1;
        i++;
    }
    return (sign);
}

int ft_atoi(char *str)
{
    long long result;
    int i;

    i = 0;
    result = 0;
    while ((*(str + i) >= 9 && *(str + i) <= 32)
        || *(str + i) == '-' || *(str + i) == '+')
        i++;
    while (*(str + i) && (*(str + i) >= '0' && *(str + i) <= '9'))
    {
        result *= 10;
        result += (long long)str[i] - '0';
        i++;
    }
    if (ft_checksign(str) % 2 == 1)
        return ((long long)-result);
    else
        return ((long long)result);
}
int main()
{
    printf("%i", ft_atoi("19999999999"));
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
-1474836481
```

Comment: It seems you are asking how to return a value as an int where the value is larger than can fit in an int. That's not possible. If that is not the question then please clarify. For example,  you could change the return type of the function (but then it wouldn't be `atoi` of course) - is that acceptable or not?

Comment: exactly that's the task I was tasked making atoa big-numbers proof , I don't know about the fact that's impossible, as long as the question asked

Comment: Either you have misunderstood the requirements or you have been asked to do something impossible (I would guess the former).

Comment: "stupidly it will return always its type" - ??? that is not stupid, that is how types work. If you want it to return a different type then put that type as the return type!

Answer (score 1):

In the comments section above you're saying: "I was tasked making atoa big-numbers proof."

Luckily we have the `strtoxx` functions but that is not the issue here.

Lets take a look to the [`atoi`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atoi.3.html) documentation:

**Description**

> The atoi() function converts the initial portion of the string ... to `int` ... except that atoi() does not detect errors.

**Return Value**

> The converted value or 0 on error.

**Bugs**

> `errno` is not set on error so there is no way to distinguish between 0 as an error and as the converted value. No checks for overflow or underflow are done. ...

If you consider, that `int` has either 16 or 32 bits, you're limited to a certain range. Not to forget, that `int` is a signed type, which means, that one bit is reserved for the sign.

The problem you have to solve is simple: implement an `atoi` function, so that it is possible to distinguish between 0 or an error and implement checks for overflow and underflow. Since `errno` is not set, `errno` is global, set it accordingly.

From man [`strtol`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html):

**Return Value**

> The strtol() function returns the result of the conversion, unless the value would underflow or overflow.  If an underflow occurs, strtol() returns LONG_MIN. If an overflow occurs, strtol() returns LONG_MAX.  In both cases, errno is set to ERANGE.

**Errors**

> **ERANGE** The resulting value was out of range.
> The implementation may also set errno to EINVAL in case no conversion was performed (no digits seen, and 0 returned).

And last but not least: [strtol.c](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libiberty/strtol.c.html)